# universal button self add class

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it posible to make a universal jquery for basically all buttons in my code with diferent ids? i cant seem to get this to work. what im trying to achieve is everytime a button is clicked the javascript will add a class for that specific button that was clicked.

**HTML :**

```
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction(this.id)" id="test1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">button 1</button>
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction(this.id)" id="test2" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">button 2</button>
<button type="button" onClick="myFunction(this.id)" id="test2" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right">button 2</button>
```

**JS :**

```
function myFunction(this) {
     $(this).addClass("animated flipInY");
  setTimeout(function(){
     $(this).removeClass("animated flipInY")

  },1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `click` event with `button` selector and it will work for all your button :

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
     $(this).addClass('animated flipInY');
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you have is more related with calling the "removeClass" for all buttons...

For that you need to change

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $(this).removeClass("animated flipInY")
  },1000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function(){
     $('button').removeClass("animated flipInY")    
  },1000);
```

in your code (or better add it to Zakaria answer).